# Can't obtain user confirmation for android dynamic delivery

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

When user canceled the download request that requires the user confirmation,  the request status is supposed to change to CANCELED. However, the state listener doesn't seem to receive that state change. Below is the example code of the listener. Any idea? Thank you in advance!

```
switch(state.status()) {
    case SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION:
        try {
            getContext().startIntentSender(
                    state.resolutionIntent().getIntentSender(),
                    null,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "stats onStateUpdate: ", e);
        }
        break;

    case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELED:
        Log.d(TAG, "onStateUpdate: canceled”); 
        //NEVER GET TO THIS LINE
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be resolved in the most recent update com.google.android.play:core:1.3.7. We can't replicate the issue after the upgrade. The one we used before is 1.3.6.